# C++ can you use '&' by itself as a parameter? What is the function call?

Tags: c++, function, parameters

I am a first semester comp sci student charged with completing a project. I am given a template and am not allowed to change them however there was one that I've never seen before and am confused on how it operates and how to function call it in main.
TEMPLATE FUNCTION

```
/*
Pre and Post condition comments go here ...Perform the transfers and build the dynamic array of pointers.
this function also will compute the available number of rooms
*/
char** tranfers(char hospitalFloors[FLOOR_ARRAY_SIZE][ROOM_ARRAY_SIZE], int &);
```

I have never seen nor has the professor taught us about using & by itself as a parameter and while I have coded the function, I am not sure what to put as the function call since int &; is not compiling.

Comment: This is an unnamed parameter of type `int&` (lvalue reference to `int`), rather than a parameter of type `int` named `&`.

Comment: In the function call you put the name of a variable of type `int`   (which this function will not use, but requires to be present )

Comment: @unit you can do the same thing with the 1st parameter, eg: `char** tranfers(char [FLOOR_ARRAY_SIZE][ROOM_ARRAY_SIZE], int &);`  In a function *declaration*, parameter names are optional and can be omitted, only their types are required.  In a function *definition*, unused parameters can have their names omitted, too.

Comment: I see, thank you for helping me understand.